# d3.randomInt is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

Please do not close this question just because it's talking about random function only.

Hi,

I have a dummy quesiton about d3.randomInt();

The output of d3.randomInt() is a function not a value.
Therefore, to get a random figure between 0,10, 
What I need to do is (I guess)

```
var x = d3.randomInt(0,10)();
```

but it says d3.randomInt is not a function.
so I tried

```
var x = d3.randomInt(0,10)
```

just incase, neither of them working.
I don't see the release note of d3 saying randomint is not available anymore.
So I'm sure there is a way to get the values.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is d3? Is it a library?

Comment: How are you loading d3?

Comment: <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.15.0/d3.min.js'></script>

Comment: What i mean is, if i load d3, and use the first code you wrote, it works. So something in loading the library probably goes wrong. Note, that i don't know d3 myself, but just reading the docs, and testing, what you are doing should work (the first example, `var x = d3.randomInt(0,10)();`).

Comment: Really??? I loaded as script src and wrote that in javascript and run... but keep saying it's not a function. If you don't mind can you share your code??? I know it's very stupid request..

Comment: Even Codepen is not working either..
https://codepen.io/jotnajoa/pen/KKpLQGp?editors=1112

Comment: I don't know d3 well enough to tell you why exactly (maybe modular, or wrong version?), but if you use e.g. `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-random.v2.min.js"></script>` (standalone version of d3-random), it will work. For some reason, in the library you are including, `d3.randomInt` is `undefined`, not existing. You probably need to read more, about what exactly you are including, and what functions it contains.

Comment: It's a function in the very old version. Thank you you helped me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`d3.randomInt`](https://github.com/d3/d3-random/blob/master/README.md#randomInt) is part of version 2 of the d3-random module. Since the main D3 bundle **version 5** still uses version 1 of that module, the method is not yet available when loading the bundle. The method was introduced as a fix for the issue [*randomInt([min = 0, ]max)* #26](https://github.com/d3/d3-random/issues/26) and will be part of the upcoming [**version 6**](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/3333) of the main bundle.

At the time of writing there is no pre-release of the main bundle version 6 publicly available. To get it working nonetheless there are several options:

1. Create your own [custom bundle](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/bb09af4c39c79cffcde4) containing the d3-random module v2.
2. Load separate modules instead of the entire bundle including d3-random v2.
3. Probably the simplest and least intrusive way might be to extend D3 v5 by adding the [few lines](https://github.com/d3/d3-random/blob/master/src/int.js) of the missing method `d3.randomInt()` to the `d3` object. Have a look at the following snippet (loading D3 v5.7.0) for a working demo.

```js
d3.randomInt = d3.randomInt || (function sourceRandomInt(source) {
  function randomInt(min, max) {
    if (arguments.length < 2) max = min, min = 0;
    min = Math.floor(min);
    max = Math.floor(max) - min;
    return function() {
      return Math.floor(source() * max + min);
    };
  }

  randomInt.source = sourceRandomInt;

  return randomInt;
})(Math.random);

const random = d3.randomInt(5, 10);
console.log(random());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```